# Minecraft broken level dat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While i was playing minecraft (using linux) the power went out and turned the computer off, when i turned it back on i brought minecraft (Feed the beast mod packs) back up and i noticed it all the "news" was restarted, i launched minecraft and my save was gone so i checked the files and i found that instead of the level .dat being a package it was a document.

Does anyone know how to fix the level dat?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "package" and "document"? Those words don't have any clear technical meaning, not enough to understand what's wrong with the file.

Comment: The "type" of the normal one says "Gzip archive

Comment: The broken one is just "plain text document"

Comment: That's odd, but not much to go on. The normal file isn't actually a "Gzip archive" in the first place. Ok, so that's not a lead, and we'll have to look elsewhere. Hm.

Comment: Ive tried putting everything in another save, and it made that save disappear

Comment: I am going to get a windows laptop soon, if that helps solve the case

Comment: Oh, what OS is this? A Mac? That might explain the package/document thing, since Macs handle types in a way separate from the actual file and it can be corrupted separately. Download a copy of [NBT Explorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/) and see what it thinks of this level.dat? If it can open it at all, it might be reparable.

Comment: No its not, and i dont know how to open .exe files on linux.. wine wont open it

Comment: That particular exe needs Mono libraries installed before Wine will like it. Check its Linux instructions for exactly which.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Where did the world go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/where-did-the-world-go). This is what I think the actual problem is, but an unclear close vote could also be justified

Answer (score 1):

"fixing" a corrupt file for the purpose of minecraft is **near impossible**.

If you wish to try and salvage your save and read what is left:

1. change the extension of the document back to `.dat`
2. follow SevenSidedDie's advice and use **NBT Explorer** to parse the file

if NBT cannot read anything legible, the file may be beyond repair.

if NBT can read it, you can copy information from it to a new save (such as inventory items / settings)

I know this isn't excactly what you want to hear but I hope it helps, Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

In the folder for that save there should be a `level.dat_old` file which is essentially a backup of `level.dat`. Try removing the `_old` so that it becomes `level.dat` and takes over.

If it's just `level.dat` that was affected then this should fix it.