# how much storage does an 80k x 80k world uses in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a server and I want to know how much storage does an 80k x 80k world uses?
Do I have enough with 150GB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much data will a 12550824 x 12550824 world take up in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/368481/how-much-data-will-a-12550824-x-12550824-world-take-up-in-minecraft)