# Minecraft world doesn't appear on the list but is in the saves folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I load up Minecraft PC (v 1.8.7), I look for the world I played yesterday. It does not appear. However, when I look in my saves folder it still exists.

Is there a way to recover my world?

Comment: Did you alter any of the files in any way before this started happening?

Comment: See also: [Where did the world go?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/where-did-the-world-go?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Probaly what happened is that you entered a world from an early version of minecraft, if this is the case, then start up the world in the next following version there is, and keep doing so until you're back into 1.8.7, as same blocks might break your world as they are outdated code from previous versions.

Comment: "as same blocks might break your world as they are outdated code from previous versions." I don't get you

Comment: What I mean is that the code of previous versions may break your 1.8.7 world. (e.g.: Create a 1.5.2 world and play it on 1.8.7)

Comment: No, it works fine. However, you might get errored chunks, causing them to regenerate. The errors only happen when going from beta to 1.8. Trust me, you don't want that in your survival world.