# MInecraft deleted worlds can't be recovered!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It seems like Minecraft deleted my world! I tried right clicking on saves and going to previous versions, but nothing pops up! I even deleted a world on the same day to test it! Still nothing! My world was gone for about at least a week or two by now.  I did everything I could to get it back! Help!

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea to use the right tags.

Comment: Have you tried restoring a previous version of the saves folder?

Comment: Did you actually go into the Minecraft folder?

Comment: Did you run a previous version on Minecraft? That could of caused it(like beta versions)

Comment: It's difficult to understand what question is being asked here. Is it "Why did my world suddenly disappear and how do I fix it?". If so, it's a duplicate of [Where did the world go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/where-did-the-world-go) Is it asking how to recover a world that you deleted? If so, it's off-topic ("How to recover deleted files" isn't a game-specific question). I'm flagging it as duplicate, but off-topic or unclear could also fit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another suggestion: If you have CCleaner, you can right-click in your .minecraft\saves folder, and choose "Scan for deleted files". If this doesn't work, try your Recycling Bin, too.

[Note: If you're not using Windows, swap "Recycling Bin" for whatever else deleted files are stored in, such as Trash on Mac.]