# Minecraft: Didn't Save & Close and now won't open

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My laptop battery died before I was able to save and close the game. Now when I start Minecraft, my game is not listed. I can see the folder of my game in Windows Explorer. How do I get Minecraft to open that game again?

Comment: %appdata%/roaming/.minecraft/saves

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can see the folder? What's in the folder? Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: The folder might be empty..? Single player games won't be saved constantly. If you crashed the game before actually saving it once there is nothing but thin air.

Comment: Is `level.dat` in the folder and, if so, what is its file size?

Comment: The file level.dat is there  2K from the day before.

Comment: The file level.dat is there  2K Dated from the day it was last open.

The folder playerdata is also dated from the last day open. Inside that folder is a file with a long name .dat extension

I copied into a new folder two files trying to see if that would help: session.lock  [LOCK File  1Kb]  and level.dat_old file  2Kb

Comment: The folder has the following folders:  data, DIM1, DIm-1, playerdata, region, and stats.

Comment: Here's a link to another question that got answered: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/329451/nbt-explorer-wont-open-level-dat-and-my-world-is-corrupted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did the world go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/where-did-the-world-go)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the file is corrupted. You can still see the file because it still exists, but you can't access it. First of all, back up your files often, so this doesn't happen. Within the saves folder, copy the save, and rename it to "New World". Then, go into Minecraft and create a new world called new world. It won't completely be fixed, but it should recover some of the data.