# NBT Explorer won't open level.dat and my world is corrupted

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I went on my computer today, and my Minecraft pc world was corrupted, and wouldn't show up in Minecraft. After searching, I decided that I should try to find the seed of the world, so I downloaded NBT Explorer, but when I opened level.dat, it says "One or more selected files failed to open." I have no idea what to do, and I really want my world back. Also, here's a link to a zipped copy of the corrupted world: http://www.mediafire.com/file/tr8jvnaqy6a8jl2/No_cheating.zip

I have also tried repairing it in MC Edit, but the option is grey and won't work. Edit and View just come back with an error.

I attempted doing what @sh4dow said twice. Once, it brought back the world, but nothing that I'd built was there. The second time, it did nothing, but when I viewed the world it was in with MC Edit, there were chunks missing, like a chessboard.

Comment: @sh4dow I added what happened when I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several types of world corruption - in some cases it just means that invalid entities exist in the game or the save files describe an impossible game state at some local point.
In your case the nbt format of the files themselves seems damaged, making recovery much more difficult.
The only way to restore your world that I can think of is creating a new one and then copying your region/DIM1/DIM-1 folders into that new save file (the region files seem undamaged). This would restore the areas you explored, but might lead to sharp cliffs where your pre-explored area ends.

edit: it seems like mcedit 0.1.7.1 (couldn't try newer versions) can open the world just fine. If simply copying the world didn't work for you, you could try loading it with mcedit and then saving it again.

Comment: Is there no way of retrieving the seed? I have included a link to a zipped copy of the world if you know how to do it.

Comment: It would certainly be difficult. You could analyze the file with a hex-editor and the specification (http://web.archive.org/web/20110723210920/http://www.minecraft.net/docs/NBT.txt), but that would take a lot of work and even then the seed might be unrecoverable (broken compression/seed inside corrupted section). You could also *theoretically* infer the seed form terrain gereration algorithm and sample terrain - though again, it would take a lot of work and might not be unique.

Comment: Strangely, it didn't work for me. I added more information in the original post.

Comment: I downloaded MC Edit 0.1.7.1, and loaded my world, but it didn't look like my world at all. Sorry if I'm annoying you with my stupidity, but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: However, when I open it in another version, this error pops up: "An error occurred while opening C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves\No cheating, please!
Not an NBT file with a root TAG_Compound (file starts with " ‹" (0x00088b1f)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mcedit2\widgets\layout.py", line 65, in setWidgetError  
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 62: ordinal not in range(128)" Also, as soon as the percent meter reaches 50%, that's when it does it.

Comment: what you saw in mcedit is all you can realistically recover from that world folder... as I said you could try manually deciphering the level.dat file in the hope of getting the seed out of it, but considering that file is stored in _compressed_ NBT format, corruption would most likely make all data within unrecoverable at the same time (very low chance of success, in addition to significant challenge). edit: only just now saw your last post edit. Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

Just click on "recreate world" in Minecraft, then you'll see the seed. You don't even have to really create the world, it's in the options.

Comment: How can I do that if it is not in the game? Because it's corrupted.

Comment: It isn't even shown? You should have said that.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `level.dat`, then creating a new world with the same name. I had to do this once, after I loaded a 1.13 world in 1.12 where the world data structure is different. Keep in mind that the player's inventory will be reset, but I assume you'd accept that for getting your world back.

Comment: I'll try it when I can.