# Can't find world in Single Player, but save file is in .minecraft saves

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently started a single player survival world a few days ago.

Today when I hoped on with the intention to keep progressing and finishing off my farms and such, I couldn't find the World in my Single Player Section of the Minecraft Menus, however, when I go

> Start >%appdata% >Roaming >.minecraft >saves

the world save folder is still there. I've restarted minecraft and my PC but the same thing keeps happening. I've tried moving the folder out, restarting my game then putting it back.

The version of minecraft that the world is in and what I open minecraft up in is 1.11.2

Here is a screenshot of what I see in game and in folder: [http://imgur.com/a/OOKfO](https://imgur.com/a/OOKfO)

If anyone could tell me how I can fix this problem that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Closing to merge with https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/where-did-the-world-go @pppery hopefully it's better now!