# Minecraft world corrupted, can't open level.dat file in NBT editor or NBTExplorer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Help! I've been playing on the same survival world for more than two years and even defeated the Ender dragon. And once I accidentally clicked open to lan

one day it was missing in the single player menu. I saw some videos on how to recover the corrupted world but all of them said to paste the files of the world to a new world with the same seed

*|OS:windows 10 | java edition  |  ver. 1.14.4  |*

**But the problem is that I can't open the level.dat or the level.old_dat file. nor in NBT editor or  NBTExplorer, and I don't know the seed.**

If you know a better method please suggest! I want my world back!

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I think the second part of this answer applies for you: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/298503/cant-find-world-in-single-player-but-save-file-is-in-minecraft-saves/298560#298560

Comment: I am using Windows 10, but playing java edition

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you playing 1.14.4? I recommend 1.15.2, it has lots of bug fixes and performance improvements.

Comment: Can you upload and link your broken level.dat file, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Where did the world go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/where-did-the-world-go)