# My hardcore Minecraft world is gone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Last night I got off of my hardcore world and shut off my pc. This morning while waiting for my laundry to cycle I figured I'd kill time by playing it but when I went to load in it was gone. I have had something like this happen before so I wasn't worried, I figured I'd just reload to the last save something must of gotten corrupted. To my horror there are no previous versions I can back it up too :(
What can I do?

Comment: You can try following the steps in this question and answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/298503/cant-find-world-in-single-player-but-save-file-is-in-minecraft-saves/298560#298560. Backup your save folder first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did the world go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/where-did-the-world-go)