# Minecraft world won't show up in game even though it is in the saves folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

How could I recover a world I have the file for, but won't show up in game?

Comment: check if you have a `level.dat` in the folder of your world

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did the world go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/where-did-the-world-go)

Answer (score 0):

To add a Minecraft map to show up, follow these instructions:

1. you need to have the map
   [image: step 1]
2. open the file so that the file looks like this[image]
3. drag the file to your saves folder
   [image]

Tell me if this works, because it should.