# My Minecraft world suddenly disappeared when I got back on my computer after playing but world files are still there

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft creative world that I have been working on for many weeks suddenly vanished out of nowhere when I got back on Minecraft after turning off my computer and eating dinner.

The confusing part is that all the files are still there, I have not switched versions and have not touched the computer.

[Here is the world files](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/sngnjgzk8b4z5/The_One), if anyone can help thank you.

Comment: If you could zip up your world, that would be helpful as MediaFire requires you to have a premium subscription to be able to download your world files in a practical manner. | Also, have you tried making a new world, then copying `DIM1`, `DIM-1` and `region` (Nether, End and Overworld) into the other world folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did the world go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/where-did-the-world-go)